# Selenium C# register field password input validation

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, browser-automation

I am currently writing an automation test that validates which password is correct and which one is not.
The loops runs until the random string password is correct and theres no passwordMustBeValid.Displayed yet whenever I try putting if (passwordMustBeValid.Displayed == false) I get stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document. Which is abvious because one of those passwords from the list is correct and the element is not displayed anymore.

What would be the correct syntax to run the passwordloop until correct password input works & then for the code to continue to run without getting the stale element error?

```
My Current code:
List <string> passwords = new List <string> (){String.sevenUpperChars, String.sevenLowerChars, String.seveNumeralChars, String.CorrectPassword};
var registration = driver.FindElement(WebObjects.registrationButton);
            registration.Click();

            var email = driver.FindElement(WebObjects.email);
            email.SendKeys(emailAcc);

            var phone = driver.FindElement(WebObjects.phone);
            phone.SendKeys(StringChain.phoneNumber);

            var password = driver.FindElement(WebObjects.password);
            password.SendKeys(StringChain.sevenChars);

            var passwordRepeat = driver.FindElement(WebObjects.repeatPassword);
            passwordRepeat.SendKeys(StringChain.sevenChars);

            var checkbox = driver.FindElement(WebObjects.checkbox);
            checkbox.Click();

            var register = driver.FindElement(WebObjects.registerButton);
            register.Click(); TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            var passwordMustBeValid = driver.FindElement(WebObjects.passwordMustBeValid);
            Assert.IsTrue(passwordMustBeValid.Displayed);
            foreach (var passwordLoop in passwords)
            {
                password.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
                password.SendKeys(Keys.Delete);
                password.SendKeys(passwordLoop);
                passwordRepeat.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
                passwordRepeat.SendKeys(Keys.Delete);
                passwordRepeat.SendKeys(passwordLoop);
                register.Click();

                if (!passwordMustBeValid.Displayed) /// OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException : stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
                {
                 var emailsent = driver.findElement(Webobjects.emailSentAlert);
                 Assert.IsTrue(emailSent.Displayed);
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is correct in terms of C# syntax since I cant compile it with the given data:

The idea is to put every password in a list, and for each of the strings(passwords) in the list, execute the code until the value is found

```
 List <string> passwords = new List <string> (){String.sevenUpperChars, String.sevenLowerChars, String.seveNumeralChars};

 var correctPassword;
 foreach(var password in passwords) {
   password.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
   password.SendKeys(Keys.Delete);
   password.SendKeys(password);
   passwordRepeat.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
   passwordRepeat.SendKeys(Keys.Delete);
   passwordRepeat.SendKeys(password);
   register.Click();

   if (passwordMustBeValid.Displayed == false) {
     correctPassword = password;    
     break;
   }

 }
```

Comment: It works until the if(passwordMustBevalid.Displayed) :/

Comment: Whats the issue? NoSuchElement exception?

Comment: Yup. I've tried couple more things with passwordMustBeValid = driver.FindElementS(WebObjects.passwordMustBeValid); with if(passwordMustBevalid.Count>0); I don't get the NoSuchElement exception, but I also don't get the wanted output of "Assert.IsTrue(emailSent.Displayed);"

Comment: You can put it in a try catch to get rid of that
try{
if (passwordMustBeValid.Displayed == false) {
     correctPassword = password;    
     break;
   }
}

catch (Exception){

}

Answer (score 0):

Managed to set it up like this

```
            {
                password.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
                password.SendKeys(Keys.Delete);
                password.SendKeys(passwordLoop);
                passwordRepeat.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
                passwordRepeat.SendKeys(Keys.Delete);
                passwordRepeat.SendKeys(passwordLoop);
                register.Click();

                Thread.Sleep(2000);

                Assert.IsTrue(passwordMustBeValid.Count > 0);

                if (passwordMustBeValid.Count <= 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(4000);
                    break;
                }
            }
            var emailSent = driver.FindElement(WebObjects.emailSent);
            Assert.IsTrue(emailSent.Displayed);
        }
    }
}
```